# Can removing GUFW create dangers for my system?

Tags: 12.04, firewall

I learned that the firewall settings for 12.04 were by default disabled so I went to the software center and downloaded and enabled the GUFW firewall gui config.
I thought having a firewall would be a good thing but it turns out that it isn't needed.
I went back to the app and it was disabled automatically (for some reason).
I removed it anyway.

I guess my question is, do you really need a firewall for desktops?
Another question would be, did I do anything wrong by removing the app in the software center?

Comment: Only you can answer this question for yourself. A better question is, what do you expect a firewall to do for you?

Answer (score 1):

The ubuntu firewall is actually part of the linux kernel, and is called iptables.

Gufw is just a tool to let you change the firewall settings, but those settings will still be there without it. The command-line tool 'ufw' is also just a way to change your firewall settings.

Removing the gufw package doesn't remove the linux firewall. So uninstalling gufw is not going to change the security of your system one way or the other. Your firewall is still going to be sitting there with whatever rules were last set up - either the defaults or whatever you changed them to be.

Answer (score 0):

Using firewalls is a personal decision based on your usage. I personally think that firewalls aren't necessary for desktops on LANs behind routers that don't have unneeded ports opened. Linux by default does not open any ports that are not required unless a program/service needs them.

If you did not create any firewall rules using the app, removing it via the Software Center should cause no problems.

Comment: That is a bunch of if's =) , should probably add if UpNP is disabled on the router as well. You might wish to expand on "unneeded ports opened"